# How to create a event handler for event handler?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, controls

I'm creating a `Custom Control` inherit `TextBox`, however, as <del>`PreviewTextInput` and</del> `TextInput` is not handled in `TextBox` by default, I wanted implement a <del>`PreviewTextInputLinked` and</del> `TextInputLinked` for my control, just for developer can add or remove these two events using `+=`and `-=`

I have created a `TextCompositionEventHandler` called <del>`PreviewTextInputLinked`</del> `TextInputLinked`

```
public event TextCompositionEventHandler /*PreviewTextInputLinked*/ TextInputLinked = delegate { };
public MyTextBox()
{
   this.AddHandler(TextBox.PreviewTextInputEvent, /*PreviewTextInputLinked */TextInputLinked, true);
}
```

In the program XAML

```
/*<UControls:MyTextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" AcceptLetters="9" Mask=""
                     Width="122" 
                     PreviewTextInputLinked="MyTextBox_PreviewTextInputLinked"/>*/
<UControls:MyTextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="122" 
                     TextInputLinked="MyTextBox_TextInputLinked"/>
```

Code behind

```
private void /*MyTextBox_PreviewTextInputLinked*/ MyTextBox_TextInputLinked(object sender,
                                              TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("test");
}
```

But it is not doing anything, maybe I'm doing wrong, but I don't know what more can I do

Where is the problem?

Comment: Why not use TextBox `TextInput` and `PreviewTextInput`?

Comment: because they are not "linked" with TextBox, if I'm using direct this.TextInput += MyEvent; it would not work, need use AddHandler for it work, and I want simplify this

Comment: I didn't get it. If i use `<UControls:MyTextBox PreivewTextInput="MyTextBox_PreviewTextInput"/>`. Handler gets called correctly.

Comment: WOW! I tried it now, you are right, PreviewTextInput need just using default event, but TextInput can not use that way

Comment: So, can do it for TextInput?

Comment: Yeah you can. Check out the answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PreviewTextInput` will work since this is a `tunnelling event` whereas `TextInput` is a `bubble event`. In case it is handled while routing up, it won't bubble up to visual tree that's why hooking to `PreviewTextInput` works and `TextInput` doesn't because it might be handled somewhere en-route of bubbling.

`AddHandler` is a way to achieve that which you are using. Notice its third bool parameter which corresponds to `handledEventsToo` i.e. you still want handler to be called even it is handled below down Visual Tree by some element.

Now issue in your code is `you pass an empty delegate` to it which will get execute just like you want but you manually need to call other delegates (hooked via XAML to that event) which can be achieved like this -

```
public event TextCompositionEventHandler TextInputLinked = (sender, args) =>
{
   MyTextBox textBox = (MyTextBox)sender;
   if (textBox.TextInputLinked != null)
   {
       foreach (var handler in textBox.TextInputLinked.GetInvocationList())
       {
          if (handler.Target != null) <-- Check to avoid Stack overflow exception
          {
             handler.DynamicInvoke(sender, args);
          }
       }
   }
};

public MyTextBox()
{
    this.AddHandler(TextBox.TextInputEvent, TextInputLinked, true);
}
```

Now other handlers will be called as you desired.

Comment: Incredible!! this is working perfectly! I think I understood this code, but I need study more about event, I have never seen many methods, example `GetInvocationList` and `DynamicInvoke`, this is my first time using `AddHandler` too. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help Lai32290.. :)